# Adding Xelement into an existing Xelement in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

For example, If I have a list with two objects and I want to put them into an XML file using Xelement and trying to loop through the objects it put's the second object items into the first Xelement name because they have the same Xelement tagname.

How can I tell an Xelement that it needs to be unique in some kind? So it won't put the second object in the first people tag but in the second.

```
List<People> people -> has two items

foreach (var person in people)
{
 xmlDoc.Element("people").Add(new XElement("person"............

}
```

example of XML output:

```
<people>
     <person></person>
     <person></person>
</people>
<people>
</people>
```

Comment: Giving it a -1 without a comment about 'Why' isn't helpfull. ;) I can post like the whole code here. But i assume that this is clear already as it is a not that hard subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind I've found the answer.

Using Element will give you the first element he can find in your XML document.

using `Elements("people").Last().Element("person").Add`
will give you the last one in the collection. As I am looping though the objects the last one will always be the one i'm in at that moment.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, still useful in 2016 :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not very clear from question but may be your looking for something like this?

```
    foreach (var p in people)
    {
        XElement xElement = new XElement("people");

        foreach (var person in p)
        {
            xElement.Add(new XElement("person")); // add other elements, attributes etc...,
        }

        xDoc.Add(xElement);
    }
```